# C Multithreading Deadlock's Thread Events

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, nonblocking

I am trying to perform multithreading on a socket in C in order to develop a connector between two different software applications. I would like it to work in the following manner. One piece of software will start running as the server, it will be performing a variety of functions including listening for a socket connection on a designated port. This software will function by it self and only use data from the connected network socket when it is established and receiving reliable data. So for this piece I would like to be able to listen to a connection, and when one is made fork a process and when data is received from this socket set some variable that will be used by some other update thread to notify it that it has these extra precision information that can be considered. On the other side of this equation I want to create a program that when it boots up will attempt to connect to the port of the other application, once this connects it will then simply call a function that will send out the information in non blocking fashion. My whole goal is to create a connector that will allow the programmers of the other two pieces of code to feel as tho they aren't dealing with a socket what so ever.
      I have been able to get multi threaded socket communication going but I am now trying to modify this so it will be usable as I have described and I am confused as to how to avoid multiple access to that variable that will notify the system on the server side that the data has arrived as well as create the non-blocking interaction on the client side. Any help ill be appreciated.
-TJ

Comment: you need to improve this question a bit, show some code and what your concern is.    Also, there is a LOT of code examples for doing just this kind of thing if you google

Comment: Guess I was just looking for a good example on how to avoid deadlocking or notification between threads in c.. Everything I find on google links me to C++ or newer.

Comment: So, you would like to create a threaded (AF_INET, AF_UNIX, other family?) non blocking server and a threaded non blocking client. The server should accept connections and? The client should send which kind of informations? I didn't understand.

Comment: I am trying to make a connector between two pieces of software that will allow them to interact as tho they are running on the same machine "almost" that is. The information can vary but the way in which I would like to get these two pieces of information to interact is described above. My code I am currently building off of just uses the fork() command to do its threading. Is there a better way to do this? Like I said I am new to multithreading in C. As well as new to sockets in C

Comment: You can do this in different ways. For example, on the server program, you can create (man pthread_create) a thread pool (a certain number of threads) waiting on a condition variable (man pthread_cond_wait). A thread is left running an event loop (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). When something happens (eg. data arrives on a socket), the controller thread add a work to be done to a queue, the condition variable is signaled and one thread wake up and does its job popping a job from the queue. Then the thread returns to sleep. This is just a way to create a multi threaded server...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear to me, but if you need to make different pieces of software talking easily you can consider using a framework message library like ZeroMQ www.zeromq.org

Comment: Good solution but Kinda overkill for the situation I am in... Just looking to write a simple socket connector, so we can send over 6-8 data points of interest in an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a double producer-consumer problem here:

```
Client side                  Server
producer -> sender thread -> receiver thread -> consumer thread
```

In this case, the most useful data structure to use is a blocking queue on both sides, like intel TBB's [concurrent_bounded_queue](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00129.html).

This allows you to post tasks from one thread and have another thread pull the data when it's available in a thread-safe manner.